# Using a global variable in Node.js for dependency injection

Tags: node.js, dependency-injection, global-variables

I'm starting out a long term project, based on Node.js, and so I'm looking to build upon a solid [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) (DI) system.

Although Node.js at its core implies using simple module require()s for wiring components, I find this approach not best suited for a large project (e.g. requiring modules in each file is not that maintainable, testable or dynamic).

Now, I'd done my bits of research before posting this question and I've found out some interesting DI libraries for Node.js (see [wire.js](https://github.com/cujojs/wire) and [dependable.js](https://github.com/idottv/dependable)).

However, for maximal simplicity and minimal repetition I've come up with my own proposition of implementing DI:

- You have a module, di.js, which acts as the container and is initialized by pointing to a JSON file storing a map of dependency names and their respective .js files.
  This already provides a dynamic nature to the DI, as you may easily swap test/development dependencies.
  The container can return dependencies by using an inject() function, which finds the dependency mapping and calls require() with it.
- For simplicity, the module is assigned to a global variable, i.e. global.$di, so that any file in the project may use the container/injector by calling $di.inject().

Here's the gist of the implementation:

#### File *di.js*

```
module.exports = function(path) {

    this.deps = require(path);

    return {
        inject: function(name) {

                if (!deps[name])
                    throw new Error('dependency "' + name + '" isn\'t registered');
                return require(deps[name]);
        }
    };
};
```

#### Dependency map JSON file

```
{
    "vehicle": "lib/jetpack",
    "fuel": "lib/benzine",
    "octane": "lib/octane98"
}
```

Initialize the $di in the main JavaScript file, according to development/test mode:

```
var path = 'dep-map-' + process.env.NODE_ENV + '.json;
$di = require('di')(path);
```

Use it in some file:

```
var vehicle = $di.inject('vehicle');
vehicle.go();
```

So far, the only problem I could think of using this approach is the global variable $di.
Supposedly, global variables are a bad practice, but it seems to me like I'm saving a lot of repetition for the cost of a single global variable.

What can be suggested against my proposal?

Comment: Why not just install or link your libraries inside of `node_modules`? Other than that, the only thing your "DI" function is giving you is aliasing. I also think it is a misnomer to call this dependency injection. You have to ask for it each time explicitly, that makes it "dependency extraction" if anything. Finally, `$di` won't be global - you'll need to do your `require('di')` in every file or assign it to your node globals explicitly. If you are planning to use Express, you might find [`express-di`](http://luin.github.io/express-di/) of interest. Maybe I am misunderstanding something.

Comment: putting all the libraries inside node_modules doesn't link them, unless you require a module explicitly. Also, it forces them to be in a single physical location, which is not a large project solution.
i'm ok with explicitly declaring a depedency (not an implementation) at the top of a file, the same way you would do with function signatures in C# - so you do get dependency injection.
lastly, the $di was tried and tested - it's global as it's not declared with "var" (you can also write global.$di, same effect)

Comment: This isn't really dependency injection. More like an object factory.  If it were dependency injection, you wouldn't have to have a global $di object which everything depends on. You would have a setup portion of your code where things are wired together through their "constructors". Something more like `var obj = require('some-module')(dependency1, dependency2);`

Comment: @ChenR - I should have been more clear with what I meant by "link them" - check doc for [`npm link`](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/cli/npm-link.html). It appears mihai cleared up the globals thing. As I look at it this morning, I do think an adapted version of the direction you're taking is fine for having an easy way to switch out implementations in a single place via your dependency map file. FWIW, one of the good/bad things about Node is you have a lot of flexibility - if the strategy works for you, start with it. If you need to refactor down the road so be it, but it may work great. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Overall this approach sounds fine to me.

The way global variables work in Node.js is that when you declare a variable without the `var` keyword, and it gets added to the [global](http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global) object which is shared between all modules. You can also explicitly use `global.varname`. Example:

```
vehicle = "jetpack"
fuel = "benzine"
console.log(vehicle) // "jetpack"
console.log(global.fuel) // "benzine"
```

Variables declared with `var` will only be local to the module.

```
var vehicle = "car"
console.log(vehicle) // "car"
console.log(global.vehicle) // "jetpack"
```

So in your code if you are doing `$di = require('di')(path)` (without `var`), then you should be able to use it in other modules without any issues. Using `global.$di` might make the code more readable.

Comment: so, in fact when i refer to a variable in a secondary module, which was declared in the main module, and that secondary module is required by the main module, the variable exists because i'm in the main module space.
now i understand barry-johnson's comment on $di not being global (module level var instead)
thanks

Comment: yea, that's pretty much it...the only way to pass data between modules is to put in `module.exports`

Comment: i have to comment on this once again, as it's been bothering me a bit - node.js does have a sense of global, "inter-module" space.
if i declare "globalvar = 5; require('mod2');" in mod1.js (note the omitted _var_ keyword) , and write "console.log(globalvar)" in mod2.js, the result would be 5, meaning that the internal module may depend on the external module

Comment: you are right, I edited the answer...disregard what I said so far

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is a clear and simple one which is good. Whether you have a global variable or require your module every time is not important.

Regarding testability it allows you to replace your modules with mocks. For unit testing you should add a function that makes it easy for you to apply different mocks for each test. Something that extends your dependency map temporarily.

For further reading I can recommend [a great blog article on dependency injection in Node.js](http://www.mariocasciaro.me/dependency-injection-in-node-js-and-other-architectural-patterns) as well as [a talk on the future dependency injector of angular.js](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_OGGsf1ZXMs) which is designed by some serious masterminds.

BTW, you might be interested in [Fire Up!](https://github.com/analog-nico/fire-up) which is a dependency injection container I implemented.